# Directory Loading Time

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, directory

One of the features of my application is to allow users to save images. These images are later presented in a detail view of a UITableView and in the cells of the UITableView. However, when returning to the page that is displaying the cells it takes a noticeably long time for it to load. I believe this is because the images are saved to the documents directory and every time the page loads they are reloaded from the directory. Should I be storing loading the images into an memory every time the application launches or am I way off in my theory. I have also tried compressing the images with the following code and it did not increase performance.

```
       [[GTImageStore sharedStore] setImage:currentImage forKey:currentImageKey];

        NSString *jpgName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.jpg", currentImageKey];
        NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:jpgName];

        float scale;
        if (currentImage.size.width < currentImage.size.height)
        {
            scale = 100/currentImage.size.width;
        }
        else if (currentImage.size.width > currentImage.size.height)
        {
            scale = 100/currentImage.size.height;
        }
        else
        {
            scale = 100/currentImage.size.width;
        }

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:currentImage.CGImage scale:scale orientation:[currentImage imageOrientation]];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you!

Code for adding cells:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UINib *giftCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GiftCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:giftCell forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UIGiftsTableCell"];

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UIGiftsTableCell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[GTGiftCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UIGiftsTableCell"];
}

// Determine gift at index path
GTGift *gift = (GTGift *)[[[GTGiftStore sharedStore] allGifts] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[[cell textLabel] setText:[gift name]];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *subText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Purchased on %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[gift datePurchased]]];
[[cell subTextLabel] setText:subText];

[[cell detailTopTextLabel] setText:[[gift givingTo] name]];
[[cell detailMiddleTextLabel] setText:[[gift reasonFor] name]];
[[cell detailBottomTextLabel] setText:[[gift boughtFrom] name]];

NSString *jpgName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.jpg", [gift imageKey]];
NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:jpgName];
UIImage *imageToLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jpgPath];
[[[cell image] layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[[cell image] layer] setBorderWidth:1];
[[cell image] setClipsToBounds:YES];
[[cell image] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[[cell image] setImage:imageToLoad];

return cell;
```

}

I have created a custom cell using a xib file with a viewController named GTGiftCell.

Comment: How are you creating your cells?

Comment: @sosborn I attached the code I'm using. The line [[cell image] setImage:imageToLoad]; is setting the UIImageView of the cell with an image loaded from the directory.

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary. I would suggest profiling the performance with Instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take

1. If your application needs to load the images as they change then you keep with loading the images as you are , but you should read apples [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to improve performance if the images need to update and change w/o the user refreshing the view
2. Load your images when the application loads but once again to improve performance read the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)